# How to disable QTreeWidget insertion on drag and drop, with coding custom dropEvent?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreewidget

I have the following code and i want disable drag and drop in between QTreeWidgetItem existing in the tree. I can not figure out how? Any thoughts?

```
def dropEvent(self, event):
    target_item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
    if not target_item:
        return

    selected_items = self.selectedItems()
    item = None
    if selected_items:
        for item in selected_items:
            item_data = item.data(0, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            target_item_data = target_item.data(0, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)

            if components_api.is_plug(item.text(0)):
                if components_api.is_plug(target_item.text(0)):
                    return
            else:
                if not components_api.is_plug(item.text(0)):
                    if not components_api.is_part_root(item.text(0)):
                        return
                if not components_api.is_plug(target_item.text(0)):
                    return
            item.setExpanded(True)
    super(TreeWidget, self).dropEvent(event)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to be able to drop *on* an item, instead of between existing ones?

Comment: Yes, basically instead of between existing ones only if I drop on an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple cases, if no special implementation has been made, this should suffice:

```
class TreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TreeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        # ...
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
```

Otherwise, you just can ignore the event if the drop indicator is not on the item, *after* processing the dragMove event using the base class implementation. Since the drop indicator should be shown to ensure a successful drag/drop operation and you probably don't want it visible if the operation should be ignored, you can enable it before calling the base implementation and then disable it afterwards accordingly:

```
    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        super(TreeWidget, self).dragMoveEvent(event)
        if self.dropIndicatorPosition() != self.OnItem:
            self.setDropIndicatorShown(False)
            event.ignore()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer (second method) resolved my issue. :)